# Access string in a dictionary (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, api, dictionary

I am having a ton of trouble accessing a string in a dictionary, called json.  This comes back from a server in an API call.  The key that I am trying to access is "Message".

Some reason the console shows that I am retrieving a dictionary in "Errors", but when I try to access this value the app crashes.

How do I appropriately get and store the key "Message" and the value " The old password does that match our records"?

CODE:

```
//json is the dictionary I successfully retrieve from an API call (see picture)
    DLog(@"feed response = %@", json);
    NSDictionary *errorsDictionary;

    //CRASHES ON THE NEXT LINE
    errorsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[json objectForKey:@"Errors"]] ;
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[errorsDictionary objectForKey:@"Message"]];
    NSLog(@"The dictionary is%@", errorsDictionary);
```

Console log:

[image]

Comment: `Errors` is an Array and not dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Errors` contains an array, the message is the value for key `Message` of the first item.

```
NSString *message = json[@"Errors"][0][@"Message"];
NSLog(@"The message is %@", message);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! I appreciate the prompt response.  I overlooked that it was an array.  I will accept answer in 7 minutes when stackoverflow allows :)